# Sum of all digits boiled down into a single digit

Tags: t-sql

I have a table as under

```
numbers
794
709090
```

what I need is a sum of all the digits such as **7+9+4 = 20; 2+0=2** or **7+0+9+0+9+0=25; 2+5=7**.

I tried with the below script but somehow not working:

```
declare @t table(numbers int)
insert into @t select 794 union all select 709090

declare @maxValue int
select @maxValue = max(numbers) from @t

;with cte as(
SELECT SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(cast(numbers as varchar(1000)),number,1) AS INT)) SUMOFDIGITS FROM @t 

cross apply ( 
SELECT DISTINCT number FROM
MASTER..SPT_VALUES WHERE number > 0 AND number <= DATALENGTH(@maxValue) ) x)

select SUMOFDIGITS, finalsum = cast(left(SUMOFDIGITS,1) as int)+cast(right(SUMOFDIGITS,1) as int)
from cte
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @a int = 709090
select   (@a - 1) % 9 + 1
```

Comment: For the background on what this does, see the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) article on Wikipedia.

Comment: While the code in this answer seems to be correct, it lacks an explanation as to **how** it works. The link provided by @JeroenMostert seems to explain it quite good, You might want to add it to your question and copy some parts of it's content as a quote to make this answer really good.